# GMSThreadException' reason: 'The API method must be called from the main thread'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I faced this error while draw polyline by using google API Terminating app due to uncaught exception GMSThreadException

```
-(void)drawRoute
```

{

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

    [self fetchPolylineWithOrigin:origin destination:destination completionHandler:^(GMSPolyline *polyline)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // Update the UI
             if(polyline)
                 polyline.map = mapView;
             [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
         });

     }];

});
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use GMSPath and GMSPolyline on main thread as well then it should work.

Answer (score 3):

From your error message, it seems you can only call that API method from the main thread, try using:

```
-(void)drawRoute
{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self fetchPolylineWithOrigin:origin destination:destination completionHandler:^(GMSPolyline *polyline)
     {
         // Update the UI
         if(polyline)
             polyline.map = mapView;
         [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
     }];

});
}
```

This will still allow your code to continue while it goes away and perform this as it is asynchronous, but keeps it on the main thread (queue). The fact that the method has a completion handler suggests it is asynchronous itself, and perhaps you don't need to do a dispatch here at all?

My bet would be that you would be fine to do:

```
-(void)drawRoute
{

    [self fetchPolylineWithOrigin:origin destination:destination completionHandler:^(GMSPolyline *polyline)
     {
         // Update the UI
         if(polyline)
             polyline.map = mapView;
         [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
     }];

}
```

or had you previously experiences performance issues with this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it's demanding to use main thread in two places

One is...

```
__block GMSMapView *mapView;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Create GMSMapView
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, _subView.frame.size.width-2, _subView.frame.size.height-2) camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
   [_subView addSubview:mapView];
});
```

Second one is...

```
- (void)fetchPolylineWithOrigin:(CLLocation *)origin destination:(CLLocation *)destination completionHandler:(void (^)(GMSPolyline *))completionHandler {

  // Code here ....

   __block GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // Second main
        if ([routesArray count] > 0) {
            NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
            NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
            GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
            polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        }
    });
}
```